# Error installing cocoapods, even though i installed development tools

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Ive encounterd error installing cocoapods. Im using OSX 10.9.2.

I got the error to install development tools first, So ive installed it, tried to install again and had the same error, tried also to reboot, still no help. 
Any ideas? :)

```
    sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin in PATH, mode 042777
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby" -rubygems /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.0/ext RUBYLIBDIR=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.0/ext
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:68: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin in PATH, mode 042777
checking for -std=c99 option to compiler... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `block in try_compile'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:443:in `with_werror'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:24:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from extconf.rb:23:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/...]

Tasks: TOP => default => ext
(See full trace by running task with --trace)


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.0/ext/xcodeproj/gem_make.out
```

Comment: `Check the mkmf.log file for more details.` - Did you? What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't yet have it, get homebrew by running:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Then install cocoapods using homebrew:

```
brew install cocoapods
```